# Define/find Word macro variables in a document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm familiar with VBA and Excel, but I am just starting with VBA and Word.

I inherited a Word document with macros and I am to update it.

For example, it has the following procedure:

```
Sub ClientName(CLINAME as String)

Me.ClientInfoNameText.Value = CLINAME

End Sub
```

When I run it, a text box in the document gets updated.

How can I tell this text box is called "ClientInfoNameText"?

Is there a command/interface that can show all the variables defined in the document and what they refer to?

I've researched but can't seem to find an answer to this particular question/situation.

Thanks

Comment: Home>Select>Selection Pane allows you to see the names of objects. `MsgBox Selection.ShapeRange.Name` will also get you that information for single shapes.

Comment: Me is a keyword that refers to the current instance of a Class.  The Class has a property/method of 'ClientInfoName" which in turn encapsulates another object which has a Property/Method.  The quickest way to get an overview of the objects and method/properties etc in your project is to use the Object Browser and select 'Project' to see the definitions for the current project.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question must be in the `ThisDocument` module of the document's VBA project. The `ThisDocument` module is a *class module* that represents the document - this is the equivalent of the `ThisWorkbook` and `Sheet#` modules in an Excel project. When the `ThisDocument` object has the focus, you'll see document properties in the VBA Editor's Property window, for example:

[image]

`Me` refers to the document containing the VBA code *when used in the `ThisDocument` code module*. (Just as it refers to a UserForm when used in a UserForm's code module.)

**ActiveX objects**, such as UserForms controls on the document surface, are "hooked into" the `ThisDocument` object - they become objects of the `ThisDocument` class in their own right. The code in the question thus addresses an ActiveX textbox on the surface of the document that contains the VBA code.

A list of such object can be viewed in the `Object` dropdown of the VBA editor's code window *when the focus is in `ThisDocument`*:

[image]

They can also be seen in the Properties list when the focus is in `ThisDocument`.